# How can I solve this error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
how much time we fire this command i need proper solution of this error

i need proper solution of this error

Comment: please share your code, we can't give solutions based on this.

Comment: in your web.php or api.php, the `Route` that you wrote is using `GET` based on your question. Change it to `POST`

Comment: for example, the route that you are trying to submit `POST` request is `/submit-report`, in the web.php or api.php (where you declared your route), change `Route::get('/submit-report', 'ControllerName@methodName');` to `Route::post('/submit-report', 'ControllerName@methodName');`

Comment: please change the tone of your question. you are asking a question. should not be demanding an answer.

Comment: Please add code snippet with your question.

Comment: Mr.Kenneth i have define this 
but this error solve when i run route:cache or clear command

Comment: @MaheshThorat the runnable snippets are only executable for JS/HTML code, and this is a php issue. I agree OP should share code, but asking them to make it runnable will not help. Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

When you use `GET` type of route in your `routes/web.php` file, in form which is using the `method` with type `"POST"`, it gives `The GET method is not supported for this route` as there is conflict between the submission type at the frontend and the route type.

Try converting your route in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/some-url', 'NameOfController@NameOfFunction');
```

to this:

```
Route::post('/some-url', 'NameOfController@NameOfFunction');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error statement is quiet explanatory! But your question is not. Without your code snippet, it is seen that you are trying to access the endpoint that is only supporting POST so  as solution do - either :

1. Try POST request for the endpoint OR
2. If its your own api, and if required you can make the end point support GET  like this `Route::get('/get-something', 'yourController@yourFunctionForHandlingThisRoute');`